# Altair: Regression over a scatter plot coloured with a continuous scale

Tags: python, regression, data-visualization, scatter-plot, altair

I'm trying to use Altair to show a scatterplot where the mark colour is given by a non-categorical feature (continuous) and adding a regression line over it. I'm quite new to Altair, though.

First, [here's a sample of the data I'm inputting into Altair](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVi1h.png).

[So far I can create either the colouring without a regression:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8B6Oj.png)

The problem is that the regression line does not show itself. This was achieved by the following code:

```
chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_circle(size=60).encode(
   x='Lambda',
   y='ACR',
   color='Consensus',
   tooltip=["Tolerance Prevalence", "Consensus", "ACR", "Lambda"]
)

chart.interactive() + chart.transform_regression(
   'Lambda', 'ACR', method="quad"
).mark_line(color="red")
```

[Or a regression without the desired colour scale.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cgg5X.png)
I can do this by simply removing the "color='consensus'" line in the first instruction.

I have tried changing regression methods, and even different feature combinations to no avail.
Is there any argument or Altair function I can use to easily fix this?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1**

Full code:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = read_csv("processed.txt")

chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_circle(size=60).encode(
    x='Lambda',
    y='ACR',
    color='Consensus',
    tooltip=["Tolerance Prevalence", "Consensus", "ACR", "Lambda"]
)

chart.interactive() + chart.transform_regression(
    'Lambda', 'ACR', method="quad").mark_line(color="red")

chart
```

[Full Data (processed.txt)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CzXUxe2tea4hyPj6I_hp6aM0BpGK5BG0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Could you include the data as text and the complete code to reproduce your issue? It will speed up others helping you answer the question.

Comment: Hiya! Added the complete code. The data is a large set (99374, 36), currently in a pickle. How should I proceed in regards to uploading it?

Comment: Please disregard my previous question. I attached a link to a .csv of the relevant dataset and simplified the relevant code.

Comment: Thank you! Just a note that Stack Overflow only gives notifications to the author of a post when you comment so you need to mention other commenting users with `@` for them to be notified of your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a base chart without the coloring and then build the scatter and regression line from that:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_csv("Downloads/processed.txt", sep=' ')

base = alt.Chart(df).mark_circle(size=60).encode(
    x='Lambda',
    y='ACR',
)

scatter = base.encode(
    color='Consensus',
    tooltip=["Tolerance Prevalence", "Consensus", "ACR", "Lambda"]
)

line = base.mark_line(color="red").transform_regression(
    'Lambda', 'ACR', method="quad")

scatter + line
```

[image]

Comment: You're welcome @HenriqueCFonseca! Don't forget to mark the question as resolved with the green checkmark to the left if it solved your problem.